# pgfplots - scatter small and similar values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to scatter the small and similar data with this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
xlabel={\(\displaystyle (\Delta t)^4\)},
xmajorgrids,
xmin=-4.96554799726869e-06, xmax=0.000104998359428441,
ylabel={\(\displaystyle z\)},
ymajorgrids,
ymin=-120.776647344602, ymax=-120.776636703454,
]
\addplot [semithick]
table {%
0.0001 -120.776646860914
4.82253086419753e-05 -120.776641857922
2.32568039361378e-05 -120.776639434005
1.12156654784615e-05 -120.776638270216
5.40878929323954e-06 -120.776637707272
2.60840533045889e-06 -120.776637436398
1.25791152124753e-06 -120.77663730572
6.0663171356459e-07 -120.776637242653
2.92550016186627e-07 -120.776637212275
1.4108314823815e-07 -120.77663719762
6.80377836796633e-08 -120.776637190555
3.28114311726771e-08 -120.776637187143
};
\addlegendentry{RK4}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The expected result (plotted using `matplotlib`) is:

[image: Expected result]

However, the LaTeX output is:

[image: Latex output]

The problem is that the y-values are very small and similar to each other.

I've tried manually scaling the y-data, but that only makes the scale larger, without showing the linear trend. Forcing the rescale using `scaled y axis ticks=true` and scientific notation did not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of a hack, which seems to work, is to use `xfp`, which handles such numbers better, to rescale the values for the plot, and to scale the ticklabels the other way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xfp}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={\(\displaystyle (\Delta t)^4\)},
xmajorgrids,
xmin=-4.96554799726869e-06, xmax=0.000104998359428441,
ylabel={\(\displaystyle z\)},
ymajorgrids,
%ymin=-120.776647344602, ymax=-120.776636703454,
yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=6,fixed zerofill]{\fpeval{\tick/1e6-120.7766}}}
]
\addplot [semithick]
table [x=x,y expr={\fpeval{(\thisrow{y}+120.7766)*1e6}}] {%
x y
0.0001 -120.776646860914
4.82253086419753e-05 -120.776641857922
2.32568039361378e-05 -120.776639434005
1.12156654784615e-05 -120.776638270216
5.40878929323954e-06 -120.776637707272
2.60840533045889e-06 -120.776637436398
1.25791152124753e-06 -120.77663730572
6.0663171356459e-07 -120.776637242653
2.92550016186627e-07 -120.776637212275
1.4108314823815e-07 -120.77663719762
6.80377836796633e-08 -120.776637190555
3.28114311726771e-08 -120.776637187143
};
\addlegendentry{RK4}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! I've also managed to make it work by plotting the difference with the last value, making them very close to 0. This seems to make tikz react correctly.